# Ruby on Rails issue..mainly dealing with ruby gems/bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I was trying to use rspec and for some reason it wasn't working. I think it lacked some dependencies or something. Everything else in Ruby 1.9 was working perfectly on my laptop though. So I did a ruby gems system update (sudo gem update --system). I then did a gem update (sudo gem update). When I tried to run or create apps in rails I get the below listed error message: I also get this same message when I try to do gem update, gem install, gem clean, etc. I am confused. I even tried to update bundler to the latest version but I still get this same error message. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

demetrius-fords-macbook-pro-17:~ demet8$ gem check
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-0.8.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/commands/bundle_command (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-0.8.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:2:in`'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in`block in '
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in`'
    from :225:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:225:in`load_full_rubygems_library'
    from :324:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/bin/gem:12:in`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backtrace indicates that you're running Bundler 0.8.1. Please uninstall it and make sure you have a more recent version of bundler installed :)

Comment: I just tried what you said and it worked! I tried to remove bundler via the command line but it still gave me the previous error message. So I went into the root folder manually & removed it, then re-installed the updated version via the command line. Now everything is fine. Thanks again.